# What is glass-like in cosmology?

Tags: cosmology, terminology

This is from *Galaxy Formation and Evolution* by Hou-Jun Mo, and this chapter is about numerical simulations of the initial conditions.

> The cosmological N-body integrator is then used to follow their motion, except that the sign of the acceleration is reversed in the equations of motion. Peculiar gravitational forces then become repulsive. If the simulation is evolved for many expansion factors, the particles settle down to a glass-like configuration in which the force on each particle is very close to zero. This state shows no discernible order or anisotropy on scales beyond a few interparticle separations.

I read some books and there are always these words inside. This may be used to describe the configuration of the particles, but I don't know what exactly it is.

Comment: It would be easier to answer your question if you can quote from one of these books the exact words that are puzzling you.

Comment: The cosmological N-body integrator is then used to follow their motion, except that the sign of the acceleration is reversed in the equations of motion. Peculiar gravitational forces then become repulsive. If the simulation is evolved for many expansion factors, the particles settle down to a glass-like configuration in which the force on each particle is very close to zero. This state shows no discernible order or anisotropy on scales beyond a few interparticle separations.

Comment: It is from Hou-JunMo's book galaxy formation and evolution,this chapter is about numercal simulations of the initial conditions.

Comment: Glass is [a non-crystalline amorphous solid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glass). Indeed, the cited text's Sec. C.1.1.4 explains "a glass-like configuration" as one whose state "shows no discernible order or anisotropy on scales beyond a few interparticle separations."

Comment: Thank you very much for your wonderful answer!

Comment: @J.G.:  That looks like an answer.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Thanks, posted.

Answer (score 0):

You quote the text describing glass as a state that

> shows no discernible order or anisotropy on scales beyond a few interparticle separations.

This is compatible with [Wikipedia's description of glass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glass) as a non-crystalline amorphous solid.